# How to if/else statement with nginx conf?

Tags: linux, nginx, configuration

is it possible to do something like this with nginx?

```
if ( $http_user_agent = "wget" ){
   server {
      listen      192.0.2.11:1111;
      root        /website1/;
      server_name website1.example www.website1.example;
else 

   server {
      listen      192.0.2.22:22222;
      root        /website2/;
      server_name example2.example www.website2.example;
}
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [map module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html).

Answer (score 21):

The Nginx rewrite module do have [`if` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) (see the linked documentation for examples), but not `else`. The equivalent for `else` would be *all that isn't modified with an `if`*.

You can use `if` inside a `server { }` but not the other way around. You wouldn't even have the condition compared in your if before a request that already needs the server. There, you could only serve content when user agent is (or isn't) `wget`.

Also notice that you shouldn't use `if` inside `location` as it may not work as desired (see [If Is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)).

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I would do what I think you're looking for. I realize this is years old, but I was looking to do something similar and hope this helps someone in the future.

```
map $http_user_agent  $user_agent {
    default all;
    wget    wget;
}

server {
  listen 123;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://$user_agent;
  }
}

upstream wget {
    server 127.0.0.1:1111;
}

upstream all {
    server 127.0.0.1:22222;
}

server {
    listen      127.0.0.1:1111;
    root        /website1/;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
}

server {
    listen      127.0.0.1:22222;
    root        /website2/;
    server_name example2.com www.example2.com;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the form given it will not work: testing the HTTP User-Agent implies, that the request was already received. That is only possible if some `server` block was already defined. Do you really want to start new servers depending on the User-Agent string of a request you received somewhere else?

If you just want to serve different content, redirect to different paths, etc. depending on parts of the request like the User-Agent, that is possible, e.g. with http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html